# Can I drop rows in Pandas using the OR conditional?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

So, I have a dataframe with several columns, but the ones that really matter are called A and B.
If column A does not contains value X or If column B does not contain value Y, that row must be dropped.

I tried using this function:

```
def removeRows(df, value):
  
  df.drop(df[ (df['A'] != value) | (df['B'] != value)].index, inplace = True)
  return df



But i got this error: 

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

Comment: You can use `~` to invert your boolean mask and assign it that way as in `df=df[~df['A'] !=...`

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. I need a way to drop a row if column A or B (or both) contains the value i'm looking for

Comment: An inverted boolean mask absolutely should work to do exactly that, but it would help if you include a [mcve] with sample input and expected output so that we can reproduce your issue. See [how to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you add an example of how you used `removeRows` as looks like it should not raise this warning.
This warning is raised on when calling `removeRows` with part of the data frame.

For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "B": [1,7,8,9,10],
    "C": [1,2,3,4,5]
})
df = removeRows(df.loc[df['C'] > 1], 3)
```

Will raise this warning.
Try changing your code to

```py
def removeRows(df, value):
    df = df.loc[(df['A'] != value) | (df['B'] != value)]
    return df
```